# Error Getting FireBreath project from Github

Tags: git, firebreath

Today I was unable to get the last release of FireBreath from the git repository. I am doing the same thing it says in the tutorial, and the result was:

```
**$ git clone git@github.com:firebreath/FireBreath firebreath
Cloning into firebreath...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**
```

I urgently need to get this framework, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
git clone git://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath firebreath
```

Comment: Note that your problem is that you're trying to use ssh; on github the only time ssh works is if you have write access to the repo.  I tried to respond to your question in the irc room but you never came back to see the answer...

Answer (score 1):

You may need to verify your ssh key on https://github.com/settings/ssh